# Laravel form wont store id from relational table on form submit

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have created an application that so far has two tables:
user_groups:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
    });
}
```

and users:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->foreignId('user_group_id')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('first_name')->length(30);
        $table->string('surname')->length(30);
        $table->dateTime('birth_date');
        $table->integer('phone')->length(8);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('address')->length(40);
        $table->string('city')->length(40);
        $table->integer('postal_code')->length(4);
        $table->bigInteger('credit_card_number');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
    });
}
```

They are connected with a one to many relationship, and when creating a new user, i would like to choose a user group, here is my models:
userGroup:

```
class UserGroup extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'user_groups';

    protected $fillable = [
        'type',
    ];

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_group_id',
        'first_name',
        'surname',
        'birth_date',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'password',
        'address',
        'city',
        'postal_code',
        'credit_card_number',
    ];

    // User belongs to a user group.
    public function userGroups()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserGroup::class);
    }
}
```

and my create/store methods in the UserController:

```
public function create()
{
    $userGroups = UserGroup::all();
    $selectedUserGroup = UserGroup::first()->userGroup_id;

    return view('users.create', compact(['userGroups'], ['selectedUserGroup']));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'user_group_id' => 'required',
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'birth_date' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'postal_code' => 'required',
        'credit_card_number' => 'required',
    ]);

    try {
        $user = User::create($request->all());

        // create relation to user group in the many-to-many relational table
        $user->userGroups()->sync($request->checked); // $request->checked must be an array

        return redirect()->route('users.index')
            ->with('success', 'User created successfully.');

    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        var_dump($e->errorInfo);
    }
}
```

and finally, my view code for creating the new user:

```
<form action="{{ route('users.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>User_group:</strong>
                <br>
                @foreach($userGroups as $userGroup)
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="{{ $userGroup->id }}">
                    {{ $userGroup->type }}
                    <br/>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>

        //.....

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But when creating a new user, i keep receiving the error that user group id is not selected, and i am selecting it in the checkbox..
Also when inspecting the elements, i can see that the id's are correct.

So somehow the checkbox value, is not stored on submit, even tho selected.
Can someone please tell me where the mistake is in storing process?

Comment: `name="checked[]"` - shouldn't that be `user_group_id`? I'm assuming the error you mention is a validation error, and that's bcs you have no `user_group_id` in the request.  Likewise your `User::create()` will require that field as it is not nullable in the DB. And since your relationships specify a User has a single group, you only need to pass a single value to your `sync()`. And to keep things clear, your `userGroups()` relationship should really be renamed to `userGroup()`, singular, bcs a User has only 1 group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem when i use 'foreignId' before. But can you try this ?

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_group_id');
        $table->string('first_name')->length(30);
        $table->string('surname')->length(30);
        $table->dateTime('birth_date');
        $table->integer('phone')->length(8);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('address')->length(40);
        $table->string('city')->length(40);
        $table->integer('postal_code')->length(4);
        $table->bigInteger('credit_card_number');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
        $table->foreign('user_group_id')->references('id')->on('user_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

If you're using Laravel 7 Above, change the 'unsignedInteger' to 'unsignedBigInteger' and the 'increment()' to 'id()'